# Laravel if condtition with two buttons

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am using Ajax with laravel, i have two buttons, Add and Update, what i am trying to achieve is, **if i click on Update button,**

Laravel **@if** statement should run,

> @if(isset($teacher))

**if i click on add button** Laravel  **@else** statement should run,

**Complete Code:**

```
<button  class="btn btn-secondary" id="add" >  </span > ADD NEW</button>

<button  class="btn btn-secondary" id="update"> UPDATE OLD</button>


@if(isset($teacher))
@foreach($teachers as $teacher)

@endforeach
<button  class="btn btn-secondary" id="update-t"> UPDATE Teacher</button>

@else

<button  class="btn btn-secondary" id="add-t" > ADD Teacher</button>

@endif
```

Comment: Laravel's `@if()` syntax completes *long* before the button is rendered onto the screen. If you need to listen for a button click, you need to use Javascript. Don't confuse back-end code with front-end code.

Comment: @TimLewis i want to achieve it with javascript or ajax. buttons can be placed anywhere.

Comment: So where are your Javascript event handlers for `add`, `update`, `add-t` and `update-t` buttons? Buttons don't "run" on their own, they need an associated function.

Comment: i have add-t and update-t functions already working, with ajax, to add and update, but i want to get idea if @if can be controlled with javascript, maybe putting them in div and controlling with div id?

Comment: `@if` blade syntax is processed on the server side in the same way as PHP. There's nothing JavaScript can do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the way Laravel Blade templates work.
Blade template is rendered into PHP, than executed to render HTML, which is sent to your browser to render it client-side. This is the moment when your JavaScript functions will start working, and they cannot interfere with what was previously rendered, as JavaScript will only 'see' the final HTML render.

Solution to your problem if you want to use AJAX, is to create some kind of API, which will be processed in AJAX's success function.